# Link Two Oval In java

Tags: java, swing, 2d

I'm tyring to link to circles with drawline , but I have a problem here is my code :

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Panneau extends JPanel {

public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
 // declaration 
                String text = "test";
                int x = 250, y = 200;
                int height = 50, width = 50;


                g.setColor(Color.yellow);
                g.fillOval(x-height/2, y-width/2,width, height);
g.fillOval((x-height/2)+100, (y-width/2)+50,width, height);

                FontMetrics fm = g.getFontMetrics();
                double textWidth = fm.getStringBounds(text, g).getWidth();
                g.setColor(Color.black);
                g.drawString(text, (int) (x - textWidth/2),(int) (y + fm.getMaxAscent() / 2));
            g.drawString(text, (int) (x - textWidth/2)+100,(int) (y + fm.getMaxAscent() / 2)+50);
            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.drawLine(x,y,x+100,y+50);



}
}
```

the problem , the line I drawed start from center of circle , I want to draw Line from circle (like Graph node!) thanks for helping ! :)

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) (add a `main(String[])` that puts it on-screen).

Comment: BTW - this basically involves a bit of geometry.  You'll need to delve into the [`Math`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html) functions for `sin()`/`cos()` etc.  As such, it is more a math problem than a programming problem.  Work out how to do it on a piece of paper, and it should be trivial to translate that to Java.

Comment: thank you for the answer I will add main(String[] args)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, I realized there was a way to 'hack it' by drawing the graphic elements in a different order.  This still draws the entire line, but then effectively 'erases the unwanted bits' by ..drawing over the top of them!

[image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Panneau extends JPanel {

public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    // declaration
    String text = "test";
    int x = 250, y = 200;
    int height = 50, width = 50;

    g.setColor(Color.black);
    g.drawLine(x,y,x+100,y+50);

    g.setColor(Color.yellow);
    g.fillOval(x-height/2, y-width/2,width, height);
    g.fillOval((x-height/2)+100, (y-width/2)+50,width, height);

    FontMetrics fm = g.getFontMetrics();
    double textWidth = fm.getStringBounds(text, g).getWidth();
    g.setColor(Color.black);
    g.drawString(text, (int) (x - textWidth/2),(int) (y + fm.getMaxAscent() / 2));
    g.drawString(text, (int) (x - textWidth/2)+100,(int) (y + fm.getMaxAscent() / 2)+50);
}

public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
    return new Dimension(400,280);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Panneau p = new Panneau();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, p);
        }
    };
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
}
}
```

Comment: +1 for the tricks ;) @user3080016, There is actually profound way to draw especially Graph drawing. You need to parametrize the location of each object with comparing to each other. However, try find the intersecting point of the line and the circle's outer line with mathematical equation `ax+by+c = 0` and `(x-h)^2 + (y-k)^2 - r ^2 = 0`:`(h, k)` is the center Andrew's solution is good, but What if the oval are to transparent ? That is why we should use geometric calculation for finding the intersection point of the line and the two circles and use that as the two edge while drawing the line

Comment: @Sage *"but What if the oval are to transparent ?"*  Nod.  Yep, in that situation, we'd actually have to do some (shock horror) ..math!  ;)